# Using IIS with Windows 7 Host File

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I am having an issue that I hope you guys can help me with.

I currently am running IIS on a Windows 2008 server and it is working properly and displaying the webpage I need it to.

We have a few bad apples here that need a few webpages blocked (one of them being youtube).  As of right now, since it is only 3 people, I am editing the host file and have configured the hose file as such:

127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com

This works perfectly, they are not able to access youtube.com.

I have created a webpage on IIS that has a warning.  When I type in 192.168.1.188 into a web browser it displays the IIS webpage I created.  So I edited the host files again and now it looks as such:

192.168.1.188 www.youtube.com

It still blocks the webpage but does not display the IIS page I created.

So my question here is, how do I get it to view the IIS webpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush the DNS cache on the client. Entries from the hosts file are loaded and remain in the DNS cache when the OS boots or when the DNS cache is flushed. The DNS cache still has 127.0.0.1 in it for www.youtube.com.

Comment: Tried that, im still getting "Server Error 404 - File or Directory not found.  The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: That's a server error not a client error. You need to add a host header for www.youtube.com to the web site on the server. The clients are going to www.youtube.com, but the server says "that's not me". The host header allows the server to say "oh yes, that's me".

Comment: Ok, let me try this and see what happens.  It appears I can set more than one hostname for it.  Reason I ask is because I need to block 5 more sites.

Comment: Im still getting the same file or directory error.  I have restarted the IIS service and have flushed DNS.  Any ideas now?

Comment: Interesting, it works for www.ebay.com but not for www.youtube.com even after a dnsflush

Comment: I don't have an IIS server here to look at but check the basics: host headers and default document and web site bindings. An HTTP 404 is technically a client error but in your case it's because the server can't find the resource the client is looking for... because the server isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Also, run nslookup on the client for www.youtube.com and see what ip address it resolves to in order to make sure it's resolving to the correct server ip address.

Comment: Im rebooting the test machine im testing this on.  I figured its better to test before releasing it to the wild.

Comment: Ok, after rebooting it still didnt work.  It appeared to be a caching issue.  I just deleted all history and boom it worked.  Thank you so much!  Life saver again.

Comment: Glad to help...